# How to get value from DataTables row on row click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a HTML page with a DataTable ([datatables.net](http://datatables.net)) with data that is populated from the database.  What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able click on a row in the datatable and when it's selected, store an ID value contained in the datatable into an array for later use.  If a particular row is unselected, the array would be searched, and the matching ID value would be removed.  Here is what I have tried so far.  It seems to work sporadically:

```
$('#businessTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

    var data = BusinessFileTable.row({ selected: true }).data();

    if ($(this).hasClass('selected') == false) {
        FullBusinessRecordIDs.push(data.BusinessID);
    } else {
        var index = FullBusinessRecordIDs.indexOf(data.BusinessID);
        if (index > -1) {
            FullBusinessRecordIDs.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

});
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to improve on it?  Does anyone know of a sample out there?

Comment: how do you add the selected class?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [**select**](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/) extension and rebuild `FullBusinessRecordIDs` on each `select` / `deselect` event :

```
var FullBusinessRecordIDs = [];
$('#example').on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
  FullBusinessRecordIDs = [];
  table.rows({ selected: true }).every(function() {
    FullBusinessRecordIDs.push( this.data().BusinessID )
  })
  //how as demo string
  $('#ids').val( FullBusinessRecordIDs.toString() )
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4rnsq28s/**